# When trying add existing project to solution, a project in a different path is referenced

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am doing some housecleaning with our VC++ project structure and I had the following weird directory setup.  In one folder, called "USBAScan", I have a Visual C++ project file, named "USBAScan.vcxproj".  USBAScan has a subfolder that is also called "USBAScan".  It also has a VC++ project file named "USBAScan.vcxproj".

My VC++ solution references a project named "USBAScan.vcxproj".  Its project file property is "USBAScan\USBAScan\USBAScan.vcxproj".  I remove this project and delete the project file USBAScan\USBAScan\USBAScan.vcxproj.  In the solution I try to add USBAScan\USBAScan.vcxproj.  I get the following error message:

"The project file USBAScan\USBAScan\USBAScan.vcxproj has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer".

Although I'm trying to add USBAScan\USBAScan.vcxproj, the solution is trying to add USBAScan\USBAScan\USBAScan.vcxproj.  Why would it behave this way?